# Check if value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var isempty = 0;
collegeArray = $(form).find(".cname").serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < collegeArray.length; i++) {
    alert(collegeArray[i].value);
    if (collegeArray[i].value = "") {
        isempty = isempty + 1;
    }
}

if (isempty == 0) {
    container.innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('survey').style.visibility = 'visible';
    generateSurvey(collegeArray);
} else {
    alert("Please fill out all fields!");
}
```

I'm trying to check if a set of fields, has at least one empty field. If there is empty field and alert should pop, if not it should do something else. I'm serializing the input fields as an array and then looping through it. When I run it, it seems that it's alway thinking that there are no empty fields even if there are some. How do I fix this?

Comment: `$(form)` should be `$('form')`? Do you have a variable called `form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `=`, but you need `==`:

```
   if(collegeArray[i].value == "")
```

Comment: @Stefan yes probably though in this case we know that the value property of a DOM element is always going to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the *assignment* operator. You mean to use the *comparison* operator `==` as Pointy punctually points out.